# Enzyme 3 not working with React 16

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am using Enzyme 3 with React 16.  I have the following unit test which was working with the previous version of React and Enzyme, however after upgrading I am getting the following error

Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 3 found instead.

This is the code

```
it('calls \'onCompleteShoppingClicked\' when the user clicks the button to complete shopping', () => {
    const onCompleteShoppingClickedSpy = sinon.spy();
    const onSaveShoppingClickedSpy = sinon.spy();

    const shppingPathWrapper =
        mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ShoppingPathComponent
                    AppliedShoppingLists={AppliedShoppingListsSampleData}
                    onCompleteShoppingClicked={onCompleteShoppingClickedSpy}
                    onSaveShoppingClicked={onSaveShoppingClickedSpy}
                />
            </Provider>
        );

    const completeShoppingbutton = shppingPathWrapper.find('#completeShoppingbutton');
    completeShoppingbutton.simulate('click');
    expect(onCompleteShoppingClickedSpy.called).toEqual(true);
});
```

I am also getting the same errors for the rest of my unit tests whenever I use a find and simulate.
Is there some incompatibility issue which needs to be fixed.

Comment: looks like u have 3 buttons with the same id name

Answer (score 3):

Enzyme 3 introduced a new css parser which now picks up prop ID the same as an element ID (as all elements are objects in jsx)

`enzyme@3.1.0` patched this issue introducing a hostnodes function that should limit the return to DOM nodes only.

`wrapper.hostNodes()` should restrict it to html like components

you can see the PR here https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1179

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the adapter for React 16?

```
/**
 * Defines the React 16 Adapter for Enzyme. 
 *
 * @link http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/#working-with-react-16
 * @copyright 2017 Airbnb, Inc.
 */
const enzyme = require("enzyme");
const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

I wrote the post about configuration of React 16 with Jest, Enzyme and Typescript, you can use it without the Typescript part - https://medium.com/@mateuszsokola/configuring-react-16-jest-enzyme-typescript-7122e1a1e6e8